# mac tmutil compare works or fails depending on WHERE bundle is mounted

Tags: mac, backup, mount, comparison

Using Time Machine to a Time Capsule - backups work smoothly. The problem is trying to use 'tmutil compare' to see the differences between 2 backups. MacOS Mojave 10.14.5 (same problem on previous OS version).

### The Application

Use Time Machine to backup multiple Macs on the network to multiple backup drives. The intent is to periodically run 'tmutil compare' operations to see what is being backed up, how many files, how much data, etc.

Apps like BackupLoupe will give a GUI of this - which is nice - but you have to manually mount each sparsebundle. (And BTW, it seems to have stopped working with Mojave.)

So the intent was to automate the process:

1. Use tmutil destinationinfo to determine a list of the backup drives.
2. Mount all of the drives (to separate mountpoints)
3. Examine each drive to get a list of the Macs (i.e. mymac1.sparsebundle, mymac2.sparsebundle, ...)
4. For each mac, for each drive (which has a sparsebundle for that Mac), mount the sparsebundle, make sure it has a Backups.backupdb node, list all of the backups (2019-05-22-111213), run a 'tmutil compare' between each entry and the proceeding entry.

A cache is automatically maintained so the 'tmutil compare' step is run only for new backups.

Since 'tmutil compare' can take a long while, step (4) was designed so that each Mac is processed and separate threads started - one for each disk - to run in parallel. Assumed that starting more threads for additional Macs would just bottleneck competing for access to the same drives.

### This Works

Use Finder to Connect to the Time Capsule (creates /Volumes/mydisk behind the scenes). In Finder, locate the mymac.sparsebundle of interest and open it with DiskImageMounter (creates /Volumes/Time Machine Backups behind the scenes).

Go to terminal and:

```
   cd "/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/mymac"
   tmutil compare 2019-05-19-034451 2019-05-18-220446
```

Output is exactly as expected.

### This Fails

Create 2 directories - ../mytemp/mount and ../mytemp/bundle (as mount points). Run tmutils destinationinfo to get the mount strings.

Execute: mount_afp -o rw "afp://tc:pwd@tc._afpovertcp._tcp.local./diskname" ../mytemp/mount

Execute: hdiutil attach ../mytemp/mount/mymac.sparsebundle -readwrite -mountroot ../mytemp/bundle

Execute: cd "../mytemp/bundle/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/mymac"

These all work as expected. The mymac.sparsebundle is mounted to ../mytemp/bundle. Can 'cd' into the mounted sparsebundle. An 'ls' lists all of the backup files as expected.

BUT execute: tmutil compare 2019-05-19-034451 2019-05-18-220446
again and get this:

```
Must specify at least one item inside a backup.
```

Can actually 'cd' into either the 2019-05-19-034451 backup or the other, 'ls' shows exactly what is expected. Can 'cd' down several levels, 'cat' some files to the console, etc.

Went down to the same levels after mounting both ways and issued 'touch dummy.file.txt' to actually create a file. This failed but adding 'sudo' succeeded - under both mount scenarios. (Within a given backup, this failed under either setup.)

Also tried 'sudo tmutil ...' in case of authorization issues, but same result. Also did some 'ls -la' commands at various levels but no obvious differences in the 'rwx' assigned to anything.

Added tmutil to the Full Disk Access list in System Properties.

Ran: log show --predicate 'process=="tmutil"'

but shows the same output for both the successful and failure cases.

At wits end! What is the difference - context, authorities, ??? What do Finder and DiskImageMounter do differently than mount_afp and hdiutil? Is some level read-only and tmutil is trying to update a log?

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated!

### Update

Broke up the 2 steps - mount the **drive** with mount_asp, then mount the **bundle** with DiskImageManager - and this works. So the problem lies in the use of hdiutil vs DiskImageManager.

### Update 2

Still a WIP, but apparently 'tmutil' **requires** that the bundle be mounted within /Volumes!

Tried to trick it by creating a symlink:

```
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups -> my mount point
```

but still fails. Attempting other workarounds.

Does anyone know if this is a true requirement of tmutil? Is it documented anywhere?

### Solved (but a hack!)

Tried adding a root mountpoint to /Volumes, with the idea of then mounting multiple sparsebundles below - but that also did not work. Evidently, 'tmutil' expects the bundle to be mounted as an immediate child of /Volumes.

Final hack as follows:

1. Create a mountpoint for the Drives: ../mycache/drives
2. Mount all drives below this node
3. Mount all **bundles** within /Volumes using the normal default name - Time Machine Backups [n]
4. Internally, figure out which mount matches each drive by listing all the varieties of Time Machine Backups [n], then mount the bundle, get the list of Time Machine Backups [n] again to figure out which is the new mount.
5. Then run tmutil compare /Volumes/Time Machine Backups 2/Backups.backupdb/mymac/...

This works reasonably well. Will fail if some other process mounts a sparsebundle with a Time Machine Backups entry - will confuse the above logic.